# Git pull requests involving subbranch of branch

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, pull-request

Let's say I have a fork of a repo, and my repo has three branches:

- master
- branch_1
- branch_1_a

`branch_1` is off of `upstream/master`, but `branch_1_a` is off of `branch_1` (ie, it was created via `git checkout -b branch_1_a branch_1`)

How do pull requests work in this scenario if say I want to create a pull request for the changes in `branch_1` and also a pull request for the changes in `branch_1_a`. Do I first have to create a PR to merge `branch_1_a` into `branch_1`? Or do I create PR for `branch_1`, have that merged into `upstream/master`, and then create a PR for `branch_1_a`? Or can I have a PR for each simultaneously to go into master (though I can't wrap in my mind how this would work)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, `git` doesn't know any "pull requests" (this is a concept of services such as gitlab, github, bitbucket,...).
instead `git` knows *merges*.

a *pull request* is just a way to tell someone in charge that you want to `git merge` a branch with another.

second, a *branch* is really just a label you give to a set of patches.

now, to answer your question: yes it is totally possible to *merge* branches and subbranches.

in the simplest case, `branch_1_a` contains the entirety of `branch_1` (that is: all commits that are in `branch_1` are also in `branch_1_a`).

if you first *merge* `branch_1_a`, then merging `branch_1` will become a no-op (since your `master` now already contains `branch_1`).

if you first *merge* `branch_1`, then merging `branch_1_a` will simply add the additional patches that make `branch_1` different from `branch_1_a`.

Comment: While this is true, it's a strictly git point of view. Merging the changes isn't necessarily an issue, but keeping the pull request clean _can_ be. If you complete branch_1_a pull request relative to branch_1, then branch_1's pull request will contain an update that includes all branch_1_a changes, which feels incorrect to me, because now branch_1's pull request is larger than originally intended.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the fork you're referring to exists on some hosted git service such as github or bitbucket, you should be able to perform the merge of `branch_1_a` into `branch_1` in your local clone of the fork and then push `branch_1` to the remote fork repo after which you can open a PR for `branch_1` against the repo you originally forked from.